# Springboot linking Environment values from Properties files but not from YAML files

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

This is strange, and now I am bit confused whats wrong in my approach.

I am using 2 Spring-Boot framework and writing simple Microservice apps.

**Project-1**

Constants.java

```
public static final String TEST_HOST                           = "${test1.host}"
```

application.properties

```
test1.host=https://somewhere.com
```

I am able to read this value without any problem i.e. https://somewhere.com.

**Project-2**

Constants.java

```
public static final String TEST_HOST                           = "${test1.host}"
```

application.yaml

```
test1:
  host: https://somewhere.com
```

In above case it is giving me the value as `${test1.host}` I am expecting that expression should get execute, but its treating as constant with string value and not environment value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
public static final String TEST_HOST = "${test1.host}"
```

Add the annotation @Value so that you can inject properties from the configuration file like the following snippet:

```
@Value("${test1.host}")
public String host;
```

The same thing for the second project.

Do not forget to decorate the class holding the config values with this annotation `@Configuration`.

[image: The convenient appraoch to load config values]

Comment: I cant keep variables without initialization, its not allowing to do so, forcefully i need to set to `null` values, and eventually its giving me NULL on IoC start up

Comment: Just to clarify, you are using config values as static and final, I am still wondering why you would use then injected properties from config file. Therefore you may approach either by : 
1. Calling those properties using the notation `Constants::TEST_HOST`
2. Or by using the above one (@Value), if you want to call any parameter on either controller or service layer and you mostly do, first declare a class variable like this `@Autowired private Constants constants`, and you can call any desired property by their getters since they are usually declared private.
I wish you got the point.

Comment: So, my intention is to keep this as a static constants, and I can reuse the variables throughout the application, all I wanted to make these constants when spring-boot IoC is started. what I am able to fix is directly using '${test1.host}' for e.g. I am using `FeignClient`, But I really dont like to use property names over there, in case If I want to change the key name i.e. `test1.host` that might be complicated to update.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot achieve your goal by using the `static` property since the class holding config values is instanciated by spring bean container. So I highly recomment think over the proposed solution. A significant demonstration picture has been provided with the post and it works properly.

Comment: Thanks @Ali Arabat, I think this approach is helping me in what I wanted to fix.